# will Microsoft.Identity.Web work with Asp.net web apps with aspx pages?

Tags: asp.net

will Microsoft.Identity.Web work with Asp.net web apps with aspx pages? if supports how do I register the authentication?.

### In .NetCore Startup.cs

services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"), "b2c", "cookiesB2C");

The above line we use in .net core to configure the identity web.

### In Asp.net Webapp which uses aspx

how do we register?

Answer (score 0):

According to this, yes you can do this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project

I don't know if  user database (table of users), and then a roles table is to be created, but the above outlines the steps required, and thus this is possible.

According to above, then YES a database table of users is required, and created.

so how to set this up is a bit much for a SO simple answer, but at least the above does outline the steps.